# Why is the variable name an expression?

Tags: c++, expression

```
int n=0;
n;
```

Why is "n;" an expression?
It doesn't call any operators etc.

Comment: i would call it an "identity expression"... some things might have side effects and this  can be used for conditions.

Comment: what if you wanted to do `n + 1` ? The operands of an operator must be expressions

Comment: I suspect the language creators did not say "We have GOT to have this identity expression feature!"  Rather, it just fell out from the rest of the language as legal syntax, and the creators didn't think it was worth making a special rule to disallow it.

Comment: The basic definition of an expression  in C++ is a sequence of operators and operands that, when evaluated, may produce a result or side effects.   The key property is that it can be evaluated, not how many operators it contains.  The expression `n`, when evaluated, produces a result (the value of `n`).   It is what allows syntax like `if (n)` (which tests true if `n` is non-zero).

Comment: `n;` is a useless expression statement, `n` is an expression

Comment: @Peter but how does "n" can be evaluated? For example 

`int main(){
int n;
n;
}`
What does "n" do? What do you mean when you write evaluation of "n" produces the value of "n"?

Comment: @Vanconts - semantically, it evaluates `n` and gives a result equal to the value of `n`.   The result is discarded before the next statement.    Since a compiler can perform analysis and detect that the evaluation of `n` has no observable side effects, it may eliminate all effects of the statement `n;` entirely - the standard only requires that the program produce the same set of observable effects (accepts inputs, produces outputs).   Execution time, or extraneous/missing instructions in an executable, are not - as far as the standard is concerned - observable effects.

Comment: @Peter but what is that value produced by evaluating `n`? I can't understand this thing only

Comment: @Vanconts   In the question `n` was defined and initialised to zero, so the result of evaluating it is zero.

Comment: @Peter Ok, got it, but what if n has the user defined type ? for example 
`class cl{ public: int a; int b; char c;};`
and `n` is `cl n;` 
what now? `n` contains not only the integer value , but some others too

Comment: @Vanconts - The value of an object is an aggregation of the values of its members.

Comment: @Peter What does aggregation of the values of its members mean?

Comment: @Vanconts - Look it up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the language designers have decided as such when creating the grammar.

---

As a more practical reason, grammars are often defined recursively.  You *can* disallow a naked variable to be not allowed as an expression, but it's much easier to define that a variable is an expression as well. Because then you can define addition as simply `<expr> + <expr>`, as an example.

Comment: For example, C# explicitly disallows naked values (variables, numbers, properties, etc) from being valid grammar.

Comment: @orlp Should I understand it as it is(that literal is an expression)?